# grey shape dissapearing and unable to get back?

Tags: modeling

[image: middle of the noob donought]So I am new, have been casually messing around trying to understand the controls and I noticed a problem-ish thing??

when I am making the shape and sizing I can click off the shape and the grey of the shape disappears nd leaves the meshing. I was wondering if there's a way to fix that or what it is..??

Comment: Hello, Lydia :). Please add some screenshots to illustrate the problem. I'm unable to replicate the issue. https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/

Comment: jachym i have the image saved but idk how to post it

Comment: Hi :). There's an *add image* icon when editing a question :). [How to upload image to a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75498/652639)

Comment: okay i figured it out. its uploaded jach. :D

Comment: Hi :). This *looks* like a glitch caused by your graphics card (GPU). Check [this little guide](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/173685/78972) to see what you can do. Points 2.1 - 2.5 are enough. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

This may be because you've inadvertantly enabled x-ray mode. Either click the icon shown below or use ALT-Z to toggle its state.

[image]

Comment: is the button supposed to be blue to gray?

Comment: @LydiaBlocker simply, blue mean active or enabled and grey mean inactive or disable. What you need to get back that grey of shape is make it disabled (grey). This color will vary on different theme though.

Comment: Should be blue when active. If you start with a new project, you'll see its inactive state.

Comment: Rather than "messing around" trying the controls I'd watch some of the very good Youtube videos explaining the user interface from scratch. Most of them are currently for version 2.8 rather than 2.9 which you are using but very little of the basics have changed. Try the official Blender one at https://tinyurl.com/y5bbqdcq for starters.

Comment: those videos have full on tutorials of making things john